# AHK Continue after PixelSearch

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to simply make the script continue ONLY after a sucessful PixelSearch. ie.

- Repeat 1-3 until PixelSearch Success
- Repeat 4-6 until PixelSearch Success
- Repeat 7-9 until PixelSearch Success, break

This is what I have now. What do I replace the break with?

```
;stuff
PixelSearch, Px, Py, 995, 256, 999, 262, 0x84BCD1, 40, Fast
if ErrorLevel = 0
    break //???
;stuff
PixelSearch, Px, Py, 995, 256, 999, 262, 0x84BCD1, 40, Fast
if ErrorLevel = 0
    break //???
;stuff
PixelSearch, Px, Py, 995, 256, 999, 262, 0x84BCD1, 40, Fast
if ErrorLevel = 0
    break
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your entire script as well as what the script is supposed to do? At this time, I cannot see the loop that you mentioned in your question nor do I understand the context of this script/ what this script is supposed to do as a whole.

Comment: I don't like when obvious right answer are not accepted by the OP

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**: You would want to replace `break` with `return`.

**Long Answer**: [`Break`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Break.htm) and [`Continue`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Continue.htm) are used when you are trying to exit any kind of [loopable statement](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#loop-statement). In order to stop the execution of most other parts of scripts, such as the [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto), a [hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm), a [subroutine](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Labels.htm), or a [function](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm), you would use a [return](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Return.htm) statement.
Additionally, I don't think some of the other parts of your script are working as you intend them to. For example, with your current usage of [`ErrorLevel`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelSearch.htm#Error_Handling), your script would effectively be only continuing if *none* of the mentioned pixels are found on screen. This is because your conditional statement that checks whether the program should stop executing is checking for if `ErrorLevel = 0`. From the previously linked docs, ErrorLevel would be 0 only if the pixel was successfully found, meaning that a nonzero value will be returned is the pixel is not found. In order to fix this in your code, we can simply change `if ErrorLevel = 0` to `if ErrorLevel` whenever it appears in the code.

**Modified Code**:

```
;Move other stuff up here
PixelSearch, Px, Py, 995, 256, 999, 262, 0x84BCD1, 40, Fast
if ErrorLevel
    return
;stuff
PixelSearch, Px, Py, 995, 256, 999, 262, 0x84BCD1, 40, Fast
if ErrorLevel
    return
;stuff
PixelSearch, Px, Py, 995, 256, 999, 262, 0x84BCD1, 40, Fast
if ErrorLevel
    return
MsgBox, complete
;put code that you want to run after the condition is met here
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: this was an answer to a version of the question prior to a clarification. I have posted a new answer that should better solve this problem.

Based on what I understand, here is a GoSub solution that runs a subroutine if PixelSearch fails to find the pixel/ ErrorLevel = 0:

```
PixelSearch, Px, Py, 995, 256, 999, 262, 0x84BCD1, 40, Fast
if ErrorLevel = 0
    gosub, subroutine 

PixelSearch, Px, Py, 995, 256, 999, 262, 0x84BCD1, 40, Fast
if ErrorLevel = 0
    gosub, subroutine

subroutine:
;insert whatever code you want to run in between the line above and the return
MsgBox, This is a subroutine. No matching pixels were found
return
```

Comment: As written, will this GoSub when PixelSearch is successful or unsuccessful?

I'm trying to get it to operate as follows:
Repeat 1-3 until PixelSearch successful
Repeat 5-8 until PixelSearch successful
Repeat 10-13 until PixelSearch Successful, then break

Comment: I have edited my post to clarify. I apologize for letting it be so messy at first.

Comment: @vtDemo I see, this will not do what you want as it. I will make a new script to solve that clarified question.

Answer (score 0):

Here, a loop for every PixelSearch loops until ErrorLevel is 0, which means pixel is found.

```
Loop
{
    CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
    PixelSearch, Px, Py, 995, 256, 999, 262, 0x84BCD1, 40, Fast RGB
}
Until ErrorLevel = 0
MsgBox, 0, , success 1

Loop
{
    CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
    PixelSearch, Px, Py, 995, 256, 999, 262, 0x84BCD1, 40, Fast RGB
}
Until ErrorLevel = 0
MsgBox, 0, , success 2

Loop
{
    CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
    PixelSearch, Px, Py, 995, 256, 999, 262, 0x84BCD1, 40, Fast RGB
}
Until ErrorLevel = 0
MsgBox, 0, , success 3
```